# Rails Application has schema.rb but no migrate files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am taking over a Rails project that has a populated schema.rb file but oddly it doesn't have a migrate folder and no migrate files. I am so new to the language but doesn't the schema file get created based on the migration files? If I run "rake db:migrate", the existing table in the schema file gets deleted. Does this mean that the previous developer manually edited the schema file? Could I have deleted the migrate files when installing Ruby/Rails?

Also, the logs display this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "nameoftable" does not exist
```

Does this have to do with the fact that there are no migrate files?

I am working on creating the migrate files right now but I wanted to confirm I am understanding this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> doesn't the schema file get created based on the migration files?

Yes, but they can survive independently. I can create my schema and modify it with several migrations, then delete the migrations before sending the project to you.

Rails will still start fine as what he cares about is the content of the `schema.rb` file.

If you want to construct your database, you should load the schema from `schema.rb` and not using `rake db:migrate`. In a very large and long-lived Rails project, you are not guaranteed that all the migrations will be able to run all from the first one to the end.

The way you setup a database is using the command

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Then from there you can move forward creating new migrations in the future. You don't really need the old migration files.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I will update my questions to post the results of the command. Question though, the rails app is deployed on Heroku, do I need to push my changes to see if this command had an impact on fixing the error found in the logs or can I somehow test this locally before pushing? I am looking into creating a staging/development env but having a quick local test would be easier. 

So sorry if this all too basic but I have been developing for client side only and just got pulled into this!

Comment: You can recreate the db, test the changes locally and push them later.

Comment: how do I test locally? so far I have been testing on the prod domain "appname.herokuapp.com", I found this on heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments but I was wondering if there is an easier way to view the same site via a web but in a testing environment.

Comment: nvm my question, just found out it's done through activating the server and using http://localhost:3000/, man do I have a lot to learn!